# How to open anothor activity when click on record in RecyclerView linked with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I made an app that fetches and stores data from the Android application to the Firebase, and I made activity that includes RecyclerView in which the data is displayed, but the problem is that when I click on any record in RecyclerView, I want to open another screen that contains the same data that was pressed, and I Try the code mentioned below, but when you press on RecyclerView, the application stops (and I think the problem is in the process of transferring data when I click on the record)
Please help me to solve the problem

The class code

```
public class EMP_INFO implements Serializable {
    private String Id;
    private String Name;
    private String City;

    public EMP_INFO() {
    }

    public String getEmployeeID() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setEmployeeID(String ID) {
        this.Id = ID;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setEmployeeName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public String getEmployeeCity() {
        return City;
    }

    public void setEmployeeCity(String City) {
        this.City = City;
    }
}
```

The adapter code

```
public class EMP_INFO_Adapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EMP_INFO, EMP_INFO_Adapter.personsViewholder> {

    public EMP_INFO_Adapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<EMP_INFO> options)
    {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void
    onBindViewHolder(@NonNull personsViewholder holder, int position, @NonNull EMP_INFO model)
    {
        holder.F_ID.setText(model.getEmployeeID());
        holder.F_name.setText(model.getEmployeeName());
        holder.F_city.setText(model.getEmployeeCity());

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, FireBase_Save_data_1.class);

        intent.putExtra("FB_id1", String.valueOf(model.getEmployeeID()));
        intent.putExtra("FB_name1", String.valueOf(model.getEmployeeName()));
        intent.putExtra("FB_city1", String.valueOf(model.getEmployeeCity()));

        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public personsViewholder
    onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fire_base_my_row, parent, false);
        return new EMP_INFO_Adapter.personsViewholder(view);
    }

    class personsViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { TextView F_ID, F_name, F_city;
        public personsViewholder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            F_ID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.F_ID);
            F_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.F_name);
            F_city = itemView.findViewById(R.id.F_city);
        }
    }
}
```

The RecyclerView activity code

```
public class FireBase_Recyclerview_2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Button add_button;
    EMP_INFO_Adapter adapter;
    //EMP_INFO_Adapter_3 adapter;
    DatabaseReference mbase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fire_base_recyclerview_2);

        add_button = findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler1);
        // To display the Recycler view linearly
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mbase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("EmployeeInfo") ;
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<EMP_INFO> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<EMP_INFO>()
                .setQuery(mbase, EMP_INFO.class).build();

        adapter = new EMP_INFO_Adapter(options);
        //adapter = new EMP_INFO_Adapter_3(options);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        add_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FireBase_Recyclerview_2.this, FireBase_Save_data_1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may put a click Listener on the item inside your adapter's `onBindViewHolder`,as shown below.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       Context context = v.getContext();
       Intent intent = new Intent(context, FireBase_Save_data_1.class);
       intent.putExtra("empId", model.getEmployeeID());
       intent.putExtra("empName", model.getEmployeeName());
       intent.putExtra("empCity", model.getEmployeeCity());
       context.startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me what are the correct commands for intent?, I tried to use the same commands that I applied before but the app also stops

Comment: @Amrklmop check the answer. I have updated it with intent code.

Comment: Hi, When I put the same commands mentioned in your response, I got an error in both (context.this -  startActivity(intent)   ), I searched the internet and replaced them with these commands (context "without this" - holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent)  ), but when I ran the application, it stopped when I clicked on any record in it

Comment: Hey @Amrklmop I apologize for the error ```context.this```. I've modified the answer; please let me know if the problem is fixed.

Comment: thank you very much..
The problem has been resolved and the app is now working properly.. 
I apologize for the delay in responding.

Answer (score 0):

You can't start activity within onBinViewHolder.move that code to viewholder class.

```
public class EMP_INFO_Adapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EMP_INFO, EMP_INFO_Adapter.personsViewholder> {

    public EMP_INFO_Adapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<EMP_INFO> options)
    {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void
    onBindViewHolder(@NonNull personsViewholder holder, int position, @NonNull EMP_INFO model)
    {
        holder.F_ID.setText(model.getEmployeeID());
        holder.F_name.setText(model.getEmployeeName());
        holder.F_city.setText(model.getEmployeeCity());

      
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public personsViewholder
    onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fire_base_my_row, parent, false);
        return new EMP_INFO_Adapter.personsViewholder(view);
    }

    class personsViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
         TextView F_ID, F_name, F_city;
        public personsViewholder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            F_ID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.F_ID);
            F_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.F_name);
            F_city = itemView.findViewById(R.id.F_city);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            

        }

 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        
              int id=getAdapterPosition();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, FireBase_Save_data_1.class);

        intent.putExtra("FB_id1", String.valueOf(model.get(id).getEmployeeID()));
        intent.putExtra("FB_name1", String.valueOf(model.get(id).getEmployeeName()));
        intent.putExtra("FB_city1", String.valueOf(model.get(id).getEmployeeCity()));

        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
    }
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,I tried to implement these instructions, but it told me that (model) is not defined in this part (I tried to define it besides "View view", but that caused another error), Also, (get(id)) is not in the main class "EMP_INFO"

Comment: i said model is for an example. model is your pojo clas.if EMP_INFO is a class and contains getter and setter, you have to use that class like EMP_INFO.get(id).getEmployeeID().@Amrklmop